# Spring boot admin client: Is there planned date for support Spring boot 3.0?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

There is no version of Spring boot admin client for Spring boot 3.0. Is there planned release?

I'm trying to monitor my application in Spring boot 3 with Spring boot admin client.

I would like to say, it is brilliant tool and thanks maintainers for their work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are milestone releases, currently there is 3.0.0-M8, see https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/releases/tag/3.0.0-M8

Some things still need to get fixed and all dependencies must be supporting Spring Boot 3.0 first. But you can already use the milestone and if there is anything missing/broken please provide feeedback via github issues.